# Argmax of numpy array returning non-flat indices

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy

I'm trying to get the indices of the maximum element in a Numpy array.
This can be done using `numpy.argmax`. My problem is, that I would like to find the biggest element in the whole array and get the indices of that.

`numpy.argmax` can be either applied along one axis, which is not what I want, or on the flattened array, which is kind of what I want.

My problem is that using `numpy.argmax` with `axis=None` returns the flat index when I want the multi-dimensional index.

I could use `divmod` to get a non-flat index but this feels ugly. Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: I am actually surprised that this is not a standard behaviour, because that would be how it is defined mathematically. Does anybody know why this is done this way?

Answer (score 238, accepted):

You could use [`numpy.unravel_index()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html#numpy.unravel_index) on the result of `numpy.argmax()`:

```
>>> a = numpy.random.random((10, 10))
>>> numpy.unravel_index(a.argmax(), a.shape)
(6, 7)
>>> a[6, 7] == a.max()
True
```

Comment: This seems to fail when array is masked like `a[a>3].argmax`

Comment: see: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RLJ5KowcCLZL4u_8WeGxPg8ijzF2iKXq?usp=sharing

Comment: @majkrzak Advanced indexing like `a[a > 3]` does not create a _masked array_. It creates a flat, one-dimensional _copy_ of the data containining only the matching elements. The return value of `argmax()` applies to that new array, but you can't use it as an index into `a`.

Comment: it's not a real copy as modification affects the original array. But it probably may be suitable for a separated question

Comment: @majkrzak It is a real copy, and modification does not affect the original. Try `b = a[a > 3]`, and then modifying `b`. Changes won't be reflected in `a`. You are probably thinking of things like `a[a > 3] += 1` or similar, which uses `__setitem__()` instead of `__getitem__()`, so is irrelevant for this case.

Comment: exactly, thats why I wouln't call a[a>5] a real copy

Comment: @majkrzak `a[a > 3]` in _expression context_ is as real a copy as it gets. The fact that you can use the same string of characters as an assignment target may be confusing, but it doesn't change that `a[a > 3].argmax()` runs on a "real" copy of the data, since we have `a[a > 3]` in expression context and not as an assignment target. (Don't blame me for Python's data model.)

Answer (score 27):

```
np.where(a==a.max())
```

returns coordinates of the maximum element(s), but has to parse the array twice.

```
>>> a = np.array(((3,4,5),(0,1,2)))
>>> np.where(a==a.max())
(array([0]), array([2]))
```

This, comparing to `argmax`, returns coordinates of all elements equal to the maximum. `argmax` returns just one of them (`np.ones(5).argmax()` returns `0`).

Comment: This will iterate the array three times, not only twice.  One time to find the maximum, a second time to build the result of `==`, and a third time to extract the `True` values from this result.  Note that there might be more than one item equal to the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

To get the non-flat index of all occurrences of the maximum value, you can modify eumiro's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9482667/revisions) slightly by using `argwhere` instead of `where`:

```
np.argwhere(a==a.max())

>>> a = np.array([[1,2,4],[4,3,4]])
>>> np.argwhere(a==a.max())
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 2]])
```

Comment: It's not effective since you get three passes and a matrix creation. Imagine we've got 9000x7000 image (A3@600dpi) - would you still insist on your solution?