# How to find the indices of the i-th largest element of an n-dimensional numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, max

I know how to find the indices of the maximum element of an n-dimensional array.

Let's have for example:

```
a=np.asarray([[1,7,-4],[9,-11,-17]])
```

Then ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3584260/8565438)):

```
from numpy import unravel_index
unravel_index(a.argmax(), a.shape)
```

returning:

```
(1, 0)
```

and indeed `a[1,0]` is `9`, which is the highest element in the array `a`, so we are good.

---

I am also able  to figure out how to find the indices of the ith largest element of a one-dimensional numpy array ([using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6910672/8565438)):

```
a = np.array([1, 3, 2, 4, 5])

i=3 # we want the third largest element, for example
a.argsort()[-i]
```

This returns `1`, which is good, since `a[1]=3` which is indeed the third largest element of `a`.

---

I would like to combine these two. So if I have

```
a=np.asarray([[1,7,-4],[9,-11,-17]])
```

I would like to get an output telling me the indices of the ith largest element of the array `a`, for example if `i=3`, the output should be `[0,0]`, since `a[0,0]=1` is the ith (third) largest element of `a`.

How can I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9483964/10708112 might be of some help.

Comment: yes, the problem is that I don't always want the maximum (ie 1st largest), but the i-th largest, which I cannot do with a.argmax().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well to get the index of some largest or whichever, you can use where:

Adding to above answer by [webDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7259671/webdev):

```
import numpy as np
i=2

a=np.asarray([[1,7,-4],[9,-11,-17]])

flat=a.flatten()
flat.sort()
tryvalue= flat[-i]

i, j = np.where(a == tryvalue)
print(i,j)
```

This will give you:

```
[0] [1]
```

I mean you can make changes on your own that how you want these indexes to be like(tuple or whatever).

Comment: yea `np.where()` @Amit

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way to do so.

```
import numpy as np
i=3
a=np.asarray([[1,7,-4],[9,-11,-17]])
flat=a.flatten()
flat.sort()
print(flat)
print(flat[-i])
i, j = np.where(a == flat[-i])
print(i,j)
```

You can flatten and then sort it. It will give you the output that you want based on your ith largest i.e. `i=3`. If you enter i=5, `flat[-i]` will give you `-11`.

Comment: This will give me 1, but how do I get [0,0]?

Comment: yep, it indeed gives me -11 if i=5. In that case I'd like to have [1,1], since a[1,1]=-11 is the 5th largest element of the array.

Comment: Works indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) on the flattened array and get the minimum of those largest `i` elements. That should be more efficient than sorting for most cases:

```
import numpy as np
import heapq

a = np.asarray([[1, 7, -4], [9, -11, -17]])
i = 2

ith_largest = min(heapq.nlargest(i, a.flatten()))
x, y = np.where(a == ith_largest)
print(x, y)  # [0] [1]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Amit Amola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2126357/amit-amola)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54046814/8565438) is perfectly good. In case someone needs another one, I found this solution:

```
a=np.asarray([[1,7,-4],[9,-11,-17]])
flat=a.flatten()
flat.sort()
i=5

for k, p in enumerate(a):
    for j, q in enumerate(p):
        if q == flat[-i]:
            indices=[k,j]

print(indices)
```

Giving `[1, 1]`, which is good.

Comment: Enumerate keeps a track of indices, but zabop, issue here would be of nested loop. I mean if this was working on multiple values to be found, let's say largest value to be found with their indexes of 1 lakh such arrays, that nested loop would just completely mess up the complexity. So, do take care of this issue if working on larger data.

Comment: Yes, good point,  this only works well for small arrays with low dimension.