# Why am I facing error in object detection?

Tags: python

```
confidence_score = scores[class1]
```

> IndexError: index 172 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
net = cv2.dnn.readNet("yolov3.weights", "yolov3.cfg.txt")
classes = []
img1 = cv2.imread('img1.jpg')
img1 = cv2.resize(img1,None, fx =0.4, fy =0.4)
height,width,chanels = img1.shape
with open("coco.names.txt", "r") as f:
     classes = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
layer_name = net.getLayerNames()
output_layers = [layer_name[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
floaty =0.004
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img1,floaty,(416,416),(0,0,0),True)
# true to convert RBG
for b in blob:
    for n,img_blog in enumerate(b):
        cv2.imshow(str(n), img_blog)
net.setInput(blob)
out = net.forward(output_layers)

#trying to show or detect
for show in out:
    for detection in out:
        scores = detection[:5]
        class1 = np.argmax(scores)
        confidence_score = scores[class1]
        if confidence_score > 0.6:
            center_x = int[detection[0] * width]
            center_y = int(detection[1] * height)
            w = int(detection[2] * width)
            h = int(detection[3] * height)
            cv2.circle(img1,(center_x,center_y),12,(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('image', img1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: the error is     confidence_score = scores[class1]
IndexError: index 172 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Argmax of numpy array returning non-flat indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482550/argmax-of-numpy-array-returning-non-flat-indices)

Comment: my question is why am i getting the error " "

Comment: confidence_score = scores[class1]
IndexError: index 172 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that using `numpy.argmax` without the `axis` argument returns the index as if the array were flattened:

```
a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3) + 10
# array([[10, 11, 12],
#       [13, 14, 15]])

flat_max = np.argmax(a)
# 5 <=== "flattened" indices of max element (15)

a[flat_max]
# IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

You can use [`np.unravel_index()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html#numpy.unravel_index) on the result of `numpy.argmax()` to get the correct indices of the maximum element:

```
i, j = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(a), a.shape)
a[i][j]
# (1,2) <=== correct indices of max element (15)
```

In your code, you get 172 as the result of `np.argmax(scores)`, but since axis zero of `scores` only has a size of 5, you get an `IndexError`. Use `np.unravel_index()` as shown above and use the returned indices to index into `scores`:

```
i, j = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(scores), scores.shape)
confidence_score = scores[i][j]
```

Comment: can you give code as per my question because I was following a tutorial and I do not have much knowledge @adamgy

Comment: what are the dimensions of score? (you can check by inserting print(scores.shape) in your code)

Comment: where shall i print the error is only getting thrown

Comment: ok, try replacing your two lines of code starting from class1 = ... with the two lines I just added to my answer

Comment: now this error is coming " TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars Line 25"

Comment: are you sure the shape of scores is (502, 85)? Your first error message suggests that axis zero has a size of 5